# Display inline icon before text

Tags: css, shortcode

i created buttons with shortcodes, and i need to add icon before the first text like this http://s32.postimg.org/codndv6s5/Bez_n_zvu.jpg

here is the shortcode

```
[button iconurl="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/wp-content/themes/cityguide/design/img/child.png"  title="Děti" description="Rozcestník pro děti a mladistvé do 15 let" marginright="0%" width="45%" iconalign="top" textalign="center" align="left" url="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/cat/deti/" bgcolor="#00968f"] [button iconurl="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/wp-content/themes/cityguide/design/img/man.png" title="Dospělí" description="Rozcestník pro dospělé" marginleft="0%" width="45%" iconalign="top" textalign="center" align="right" url="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/cat/dospeli/" bgcolor="#00968f"] [rule type="clear"]
```

and here is the site >http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal

i try to add css float:left, display:inline-block but not help
please advise, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with css in console and this should work for you. Remove the `span class icon` and add the image directly with the `text` and `align image in middle vertically` After this you will need to increase top padding of span class `text` accordingly

```
    <span class="wrap">
     <span class="text" style="text-align:center;padding-top: 10px;/* display: inline-block; */">
      <span class="title" style="">
            <img src="http://www.yakna.cz/neuroportal/wp-content/themes/cityguide/design/img/child.png" alt="button icon" class="load-finished" style="
        vertical-align: middle;
    "> Děti         </span>
<span class="description" style="">
    Rozcestník pro děti a mladistvé do 15 let</span>
</span></span>
```

This is how it looks :
[image]

Comment: Replace the entire existing code in between `<span class="wrap">` with this one

Comment: I dont know, how to change this html lines if its shortcode
 
its possible to implement other way?

Answer (score 1):

this page could help you: [How to align inline image with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424003/how-to-align-inline-image-with-text)

If not, try to set `floating:left` to your "Dospělí" icon.